# jQuery - Each counting resetting issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the currentpage number using jQuery each function. This is how I am doing it

```
var CurrentPageView = 1;
var check = true;
var Bookmark = [];
var CurPage = 1;
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if (check) {
            var PagesPosition = [];
            var CurrentWindowPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
            var CurrentCenterWindowPos = CurrentWindowPosition + $(window).height() / 2;



            $(".Page").each(function() {
                var PagePos = $(this).offset().top;
                if (PagePos / CurrentCenterWindowPos <= 1) {
                    CurPage = $(this).index() + 1;
                }
            });
            $(".CurrPageNumber").val(CurPage);
            CurrentPageView = CurPage;            
        }
    });
});
```

And it is working pretty well. If i am scrolling up and down he changes and gives me the currentpage number. The problem happens if between those  with the class page there is something like a span. When this happens the counter resets to 1..

[image]

I would like to know if there is a way to keep the counting working for every div with the class "A4 Portrait" even if inside a span.

So instead of the actual count

```
1
2
1
2
```

It would be

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: It may work well, but it is very greedy. Each time the window scrolls by 1 pixel, the scripts builds a `$(window)` object, then browses the whole dom looking for `".Page"`, then builds a `$(".Page")` array of objects. Same thing for `$(".CurrPageNumber")`. You really should cache all these variables before the `.scroll()` and reuse them : `var $Pages = $(".Page")` and then `$Pages.forEach()`. Massive performance improvement.

Comment: What do you mean `Why building the whole site?`

Comment: @JeremyThille thanks for the advise, i can already notice a small performance improvement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the index in the list of `.Page` instead of the index in its parent:

```
$(".Page").each(function(i) {
    var PagePos = $(this).offset().top;
    if (PagePos / CurrentCenterWindowPos <= 1) {
        CurPage = i + 1; // Use the index in the array.
    }
});
$(".CurrPageNumber").val(CurPage);
CurrentPageView = CurPage;
```

Comment: These are those times when i think "What a simple and obvious solution". Really appreciate the help, it worked perfectly.